# XPages: How to use data in client JS as data source of dataview control?

Tags: xpages

I use client JS to collect some data and want to use these data as data source of some common xpages controls, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean a data source for a ViewPanel, DataTable, or Repeat?

- Put the data in a hidden field with client js.
- Execute a server side action. (Within the server side action you can place the data from the hidden field into a scope variable, if desired)
- Execute a partial refresh from the server side action and make sure you are refreshing the control that needs to use the client side data as a data source.
- Point the data source of the control to the hidden field (or scope variable if that's what you used)
- Manipulate the data as necessary.  For example, if your field contains "one,two,three" as a value you need to turn that into an array with string.split().